# Regex won't work on pattern attribute on a text field

Tags: html, regex

When i get to insert this to the pattern attribute in a text field, it doesn't accept inputs that should be accepted. However, it is accepted and is tested [here](http://regexpal.com/).

here is my regex for checking two consecutive years from 1900-2099. e.g 2001-2002

```
pattern="(^((?=\d{4}-\d{4})(?=[0-9]{4}$|1999-2000|([0-9]{2})[0-8]9-\1[1-9]0|([0-9]{3})[0-8]-\2[1-9])(?:19|20)(?=[^-]*$|([0-9]).*\3.$|09.*10$|19.*20$|29.*30$|39.*40$|49.*50$|59.*60$|69.*70$|79.*80$|89.*90$|99.*00$)[0-9](?=[^-]*$|0.*1$|1.*2$|2.*3$|3.*4$|4.*5$|5.*6$|6.*7$|7.*8$|8.*9$|9.*0$)[0-9](?:-[0-9]{4})?)$)"
```

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML? And what language are you using the RegExp in, it's possible your RegExp engine doesn't support features you're using.

Comment: You may want to use regex to detect that you have two adjacent numbers, but you should really parse them to perform any comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I used this **checkYear** to check the year by parsing it. But even if it alerts and works, the user can still submit it by entering so I added functions **check2** and on every **load** of the page, i call that function to check if the input is valid. If so, then **enable** the submit button, if not, then **disable**.

```
    <script>
        function checkYear() { //checks year
            var year = document.getElementById('hpw').value.split('-');
            if((parseInt(year[0])+1==parseInt(year[1]))&&(parseInt(year[0])>=1900)&&(parseInt(year[1])<=2099)){
                alert('Great!');
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                alert('Year should be consecutive (e.g 2011-2012)');
                document.getElementById('hpw').select();
                return 0;
            }
        }

        function check2() { //disables button if checkYear is not met so that it will prohibit the submission of the form if it is failed - acts like required plus pattern attribute of html
            if(checkYear()==0){
                //alert('fail2!');
                document.getElementById('submitbutton').disabled = true;
            }
            else{
                //alert('Great2!');
                document.getElementById('submitbutton').disabled = false;
            }
        }   
        window.onload = function() {    //every load, check the fields to be checked
            check2();
        }
    </script>
```